# Cannot perform addition in javascript (Firebase cloud function)?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

When i perform addition numbers were get concatinated instead of adding?,
 I tried every possible way adding + to in front of variable, multiplying with 1 and using Number,parseInt and parseFloat but it will give some errors

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const PERCENTAGE = 0.05;

const CONST_INCREMENT = 2;

exports.calculatFinalPrice = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const amount = request.query.amount;

  const preamount =  amount*PERCENTAGE;

  var final_amount =amount+preamount+CONST_INCREMENT;


  response.send(final_amount);

});
```

RangeError: Invalid status code: NaN
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:200:11)

RangeError: Invalid status code: 1050
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:200:11)

Comment: Query variables are always string, so at the very least you'll need to convert it to a number before you can perform any calculation on it. If that doesn't work, `console.log(request.query.amount)` to see what the value is.

Comment: You should be able to `parseInt(request.query.amount)`. Are you sure that's not working?  Are you sure the amount is exactly what you expect?  How exactly are you invoking the url that should be sending the amount?